# Confused! The differences between "coconut juice", "coconut water", "coconut milk", "coconut cream"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-meaning

> **[juice](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/juice_1?q=juice)** [uncountable, countable] the liquid that comes from fruit or
>   vegetables; a drink made from this
>
> a glass of fruit juice
>
> a carton of apple juice
>
> lemon/lime juice
>
> Add the juice of two lemons.
>
> Two orange juices, please.

---

> **[coconut](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/coconut?q=coconut)** [countable] the large nut of a tropical tree called a coconut palm. It grows inside a hard shell and contains a soft white
>   substance that can be eaten and juice that can be drunk.
>
> She broke open the coconut and drank its sweet milk.
>
> a bay fringed with swaying coconut palms
>
> huge bunches of fresh coconuts

---

> **[milk](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/milk_1?q=milk)**: the white juice of some plants and trees
>
> The recipe uses fresh coconut milk and lime juice.
>
> Serve with a glass of sweet, creamy almond milk.

In the dictionary, it seems that coconut juice or coconut milk are the same.

But [some sources](https://www.google.com/search?q=coconut%20milk%20or%20juice&oq=coconut%20milk%20or%20juice&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.4952j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) define "**coconut milk**" differently

> **[Coconut milk](https://www.google.com/search?q=coconut%20milk%20or%20juice&oq=coconut%20milk%20or%20juice&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.4952j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**: As the coconut matures, the juice or water is replaced
>   by coconut meat. Coconut milk is made by simmering one part shredded
>   coconut meat with one part water and then straining the mixture
>   through a cheesecloth, squeezing out as much liquid as possible

According to this article, "**coconut water**" is actually the coconut juice or coconut milk that we found in the dictionary above. But the article refers "**coconut milk**" is a kind of man-made product, that we have to cook something to make "**coconut milk**".

So what are the differences between "**coconut juice**", "**coconut water**", "**coconut milk**", "**coconut cream**"?

Comment: To judge from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coconut_water), the terminology is confusing. It seems it's as much a cookery question as it is a language one. However, I would suggest that as a coconut isn't a juicy fruit, it's incorrect to call the liquid inside it _juice_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a coconut there is some water that you can drink.  It is usually called "coconut water" and sometimes "coconut juice".  But it is very rare in England, because fresh, green coconuts are not usually in the shops.

When cooking south and south-east asian food, you sometimes make coconut milk by blending water (ie hot tap water) with the white meat of the coconut. The result is a white milky liquid that you can put in curries.

You can also buy coconut milk in the shops. You can also buy milk that has had some (or most) of its water removed (to make it easier to handle and to preserve it) This is a thick cream, and is called coconut cream.  You would normally add water to this to turn it back to milk when you are cooking with it.

This is how most cooks would use these words.  But, remember that coconuts are not often found growing in England or the USA, and there is little tradition of drinking fresh coconut water. So there is variation in use, and people will use the terms differently (ie they make mistakes) Some people will probably call the watery stuff inside the green coconut "milk" just because they don't know much about cooking with coconuts.

Properly the "milk" and "cream" are man-made, and the "water" and "juice" are what is found in the coconut. But sometimes people will use the wrong word.